# Append variables to URL after pagination's '/page/x'

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using a couple URI variables to handle sorting a table, like this

`.../page/7/sortby/serial_number/orderby/desc`

as you can see, I'm also using the built in CI pagination library. My problem right now is that the links created with `$this->pagination->create_links();` strip off sorting variables from the URI, making it difficult to maintain these sorting options between pages.

How can I go about appending these variables `sortby/foo/orderby/bar` to the URI of links created by the pagination library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answers thanks to WesleyMurch leading me in the right direction. In order to always have the page variable as the last in the uri (which is necessary when using CI's pagination library), I used this

```
$totalseg = $this->uri->total_segments();
$config['uri_segment'] = $totalseg;
```

then following WesleyMurch's idea, I rebuilt the base_url,

```
$segments = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
unset($segments['page']);   //so page doesn't show up twice
$uri = $this->uri->assoc_to_uri($segments);
$config['base_url'] = site_url()."/controller/method/".$uri."/page/";
```

and of course initialize the pagination with all the correct config options

`$this->pagination->initialize($config);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `base_url` option, and the page number segments will have to be last. It's a little annoying, but I think it's the simplest way.

```
// Get the current url segments
$segments = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();

// Unset the "page" segment so it's not there twice
$segments['page'] = null;

// Put the uri back together
$uri = $this->uri->assoc_to_uri($segmenmts);

$config['base_url'] = 'controller/method/'.$uri.'/page/';
// other config here

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Comment: thanks! you led me to the correct answer, but this wasn't exactly it. for that reason I'm posting my solution and marking it as the answer so that others can see the full answer easily

Answer (score 1):

I use the answer of ejfrancis but...

If for some reason the user put not numeric or negative number in the url's page var, i suggest make a validation before set the $config['uri_segment'], like this one:

```
    $totalseg = $this->uri->segment($totalseg)>0 && 
           is_numeric($this->uri->segment($totalseg))?
                        $totalseg : NULL;
```

I hope it help!